# Retornando o número de espaços em uma String

Tags: php

Nem só espaços, mas qualquer outra letra, pro exemplo.

Existe alguma função que me retorne isto?

Já tentei :

```
public function verifica_nome()
{
    return substr_count($this->name, " ");
}
```

Mas a mesma sempre me retorna 0...

Comment: Mande imprimir o `$this->name` antes de executar para ver se ela está com o texto que acha que está. O seu problema real deve ser este.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize esta função do php que retorna um inteiro com a quantidade:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php

```
echo substr_count("oi tudo bem?"," ");
```

Mostrará:

```
2
```

Comment: Eu estava utilizando esta função. Mas ela sempre me retornava 0.

Comment: Olhe aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_substr_count